# Python conditional formatting for coloring of string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe with object columns shown below. The columns contain string values with a score and a delta score in brackets

```
Manager     engage_final   engage_q1_final    engage_q2_final    engage_q3_final   
John        64% (+5)       66% (+4)           65% (+6)           64% (+5)
Peter       92% (-2)       90% (-1)           91% (-7)           93% (-4) 
Jennifer    98% (nan)      96% (nan)          97% (nan)          96% (nan)
Patricia    95% (0)        95% (-1)           96% (+1)           94% (0)  
Melissa     88% (+3)       85% (+2)           84% (0)            90% (-6)
```

I would like to apply some conditional formatting in terms of the delta scores before I output this into excel. The conditional formatting involves having some colors applied based on the values in the brackets. Darkest green for more than +5, dark green for +5, lighter green for +4, darkest orange for less than -5, dark orange for -5, lighter orange for -4 etc.

I have tried the following code which is not the most elegant and also, it does not work. Can't seem to find many solutions for conditional formatting. Any form of help is much appreciated, thank you.

```
columns = [col for col in engage_df.columns if 'engage' in col]


def highlight (engage_df):
    if engage_df[columns].str.contains("+5"):
        return ['background-color: #64A064']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("+4"):
        return ['background-color: #78B478']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("+3"):
        return ['background-color: #8CC88C']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contain("+2"):
        return ['background-color: #A0DCA0']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("+1"):
        return ['background-color: #B4F0B4']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("+"):
        return ['background-color: #508C50']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("-5"):
        return ['background-color: #F48200']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("-4"):
        return ['background-color: #FF9600']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("-3"):
        return ['background-color: #FFAA00']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("-2"):
        return ['background-color: #FFBE00']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("-1"):
        return ['background-color: #FFD200']
    elif engage_df[columns].str.contains("-"):
        return ['background-color: #FF6E00']
    else:
        return ['background-color: white']

engage_df.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)
```

Comment: do you mean formatting for when you inspect the dataframe from the variable inspector of your ide, or for when you export to excel?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous, I meant when it is exported to excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create dictionaries for mapping values ans pass to [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) only for columns in subset parameter:

```
def highlight(x):
    #get +-INT values between ()
    s1 = x.str.extract('\(([+-]*\d+)\)', expand=False)
    #Series with default values
    s = pd.Series('background-color: white', index=x.index)
    #dictionary for match
    d = {'+5':'background-color: #64A064', '+4': 'background-color: #78B478'}
    #if match colot between () add value from dictionary
    for k, v in d.items():
        s.loc[s1 == k] = v
         
    #replace >5 and <-5 values comparing floats values
    s.loc[s1.astype(float) > 5] = 'background-color: #508C50'  
    s.loc[s1.astype(float) < -5] = 'background-color: #FF6E00'  
    return s


cols = [col for col in engage_df.columns if 'engage' in col]
engage_df.style.apply(highlight, subset=cols, axis=1).to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: this seems to be working! But is there a way to have any value more than +5 as 'background-color:: #508C50' and any value less than -5 as 'background-color: #FF6E00'

Comment: @wjie08 - I miss it in question. Added solution for it.